# Dynamic Survey DB Design

Tags: sql-server, database-design

My problem is that I need to digitize a series of 5 ticksheets/surveys.

Each one has a generic structure but are used at different times and have different questions; each one has at least 50-75 questions of varying data types. Each question also has a category which is relevant to an outside system that this information will be ported to (moving the information is outside the scope of this project).

I would like to have it so I don't need 1 table for each form with 50-ish columns.

As of now I have a design which I believe is the proper way to do it; but I have concerns about performance and would like to know if this is best way to do it in case they wish to add more surveys.

My DB diagram is as follows, using SQL Server 2012.

[image]

**Missing junction table between Question and SurveyType deciding which questions will be displayed on each form**

The answer's type in SurveyQuestions will be enforced in the App(unless there's a better way in the DB).

My main concern with this approach is that SurveyQuestion will become too large by sheer volume of rows.  Any input or other approaches would be greatly appreciated.

There is also another option I just put together; by separating out the survey types in base types I think it will take away some of the potential issue with performance.

2:
[image]

Comment: Are the questions (potentially) common to more than one of the surveys?

Comment: @seventyeightist in the future that is a possibility.

Comment: OK... are there any particular problems you have with performance already? I'm assuming you have a standard clustered index etc on these tables as per the defined PKs.

I haven't written a complete answer but my schema would look something like - SurveyType (ID and Description), Survey (ID and SurveyTypeID, possibly other things such as Name and Description), Question (ID and QuestionWording, possibly Category with another QuestionCategory table if needed), SurveyQuestion (ID, SurveyID, QuestionID, possibly some kind of sequence to control the order of the questions if not in "ID" order.)

Comment: No performance issues yet; just want to get this right before I start it.  So as long as its properly indexed I shouldn't worry about performance if the SurveyQuestion table gets to the millions?